# Javascript function not working inside a href tag

Tags: javascript, c#, html, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on WP8.1. Where I am using  webview. The data comes from the server and I am loading the content using webview.NavigateToString(). The script contains following

```
function Action7614aba6(){

   Notify7614aba6(click_urls7614aba6,1);
 }
 Notify7614aba6(impression_urls7614aba6);

 var markup7614aba6 = '';
 markup7614aba6 += '<a href="javascript:Action7614aba6();">';

 markup7614aba6 += '<img src="http://img.com/i/320x50_1/1bad36c591cef91cf20585883bc7e2d8.png?40479_126850_7614aba6" alt=""  border="0" />';
 markup7614aba6 += '</a>';
 document.write(markup7614aba6);
```

This code contains calling javascript function from "a href" tag. So whenever the user clicks that javascript function will be called. But in Wp8.1 whenever i click on the image, the javascript function is not called. I tried registering with onclick()

```
  <a onclick="Action7614aba6();">
```

This is working. But as per project is concerned (consistency across all platforms) the client will be giving in

```
  <a href="javascript:Action7614aba6();"> javascript function.
```

The above function working fine on IE10,IE11 on the desktop but is not working on IE11 on windows phone 8.1.

Please help.

Comment: Just tested this simple js-fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/0L8a14h7/) on my windows phone 8.1. and it's working. What about your phone? And what do you mean with "giving in a href" ?

Comment: This is working in wp8 project, but not in wp8.1 webview. Dont know what is the issue.

Comment: Its not working. "giving in a href" means including javascript function in <a href> tag.

Comment: @OschtärEi simple js-fiddle is calling the method, its not windows phone browser.